# ascending the data value from SQLite android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

i have problem with the ascending by date ...I want to group all the date by listDate( date format ) , i think something wrong in my code ..

```
public Cursor getAll() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (database.rawQuery("SELECT " + SQLiteHelper.listId + " as _id, "
                + SQLiteHelper.listName + "," + SQLiteHelper.listDate + ","
                + SQLiteHelper.listDest + " FROM " + SQLiteHelper.listTable
                + " ORDER BY " + SQLiteHelper.listDate+ "ASC",null));

    }


private static final String CREATE_SHOPPLINGLIST_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + listTable
            + " ("
            + listId
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + listName
            + " TEXT, "
            + listDest + " TEXT," + listDate + " INTEGER)";
```

hope anyone can correct me my mistake ...

Comment: wat is the format of listDate stored in DB

Comment: i store listDate in Integer

Comment: how you differ from output ? in other word what is your date format ans what you get right now ?

Comment: @chintan khetiya ,i cannot get any output is i add one ASC in query

Comment: @raju ,the format is year-month-day ,2012-11-24

Comment: @johnk try storing date in epoch time and then sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
return (database.rawQuery("SELECT " + SQLiteHelper.listId + " as _id, "
                + SQLiteHelper.listName + "," + SQLiteHelper.listDate + ","
                + SQLiteHelper.listDest + " FROM " + SQLiteHelper.listTable
                + " ORDER BY " + SQLiteHelper.listDate+ " ASC",null));
```

Give space in `" ASC"`.